# Trimming zero elements at the end in a decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

To pretty print my calculation results I wrote a decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps

def print_disp(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapping(*args, **kwargs):
        disp, disp_std = f(*args, **kwargs)
        labels = ('GD', 'GDD','TOD', 'FOD', 'QOD')
        for i, (label, disp_item, disp_std_item) in enumerate(zip(labels, disp, disp_std)):
            print(f'{label} = {disp_item:.5f} ± {disp_std_item:.5f} fs^{i+1}')
        return disp, disp_std
    return wrapping
```

which can be used the following way:

```py
import numpy as np

@print_disp
def calc():
    disp = np.array([1, 0, 7, 0, 0])
    disp_std = np.array([0.1, 0, 0.7, 0, 0])
    return disp, disp_std
```

and it returns

```
GD = 1.00000 ± 0.10000 fs^1
GDD = 0.00000 ± 0.00000 fs^2
TOD = 7.00000 ± 0.70000 fs^3
FOD = 0.00000 ± 0.00000 fs^4
QOD = 0.00000 ± 0.00000 fs^5
```

Which is fine. However, I want to avoid printing redundant 0 lines, but I only want to trim the zeros at the end, so the line GDD = 0 should stay. Because of this reason I couldn't add something like `if disp item != 0: print(..)` to the decorator body. The desired behaviour is:

```
GD = 1.00000 ± 0.10000 fs^1
GDD = 0.00000 ± 0.00000 fs^2
TOD = 7.00000 ± 0.70000 fs^3
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question. I've removed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print only the first line with zeroes, you can modify the decorator like this to keep track of whether or not such a line is printed:

```
def print_disp(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapping(*args, **kwargs):
        zero_printed = False
        disp, disp_std = f(*args, **kwargs)
        labels = ('GD', 'GDD','TOD', 'FOD', 'QOD')
        for i, (label, disp_item, disp_std_item) in enumerate(zip(labels, disp, disp_std)):
            if disp_item == 0 and zero_printed:
                continue
            zero_printed |= disp_item == 0
            print(f'{label} = {disp_item:.5f} ± {disp_std_item:.5f} fs^{i+1}')
        return disp, disp_std
    return wrapping
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
from functools import wraps

def print_disp(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapping(*args, **kwargs):
        disp, disp_std = f(*args, **kwargs)
        labels = ('GD', 'GDD','TOD', 'FOD', 'QOD')
        for i, (label, disp_item, disp_std_item) in enumerate(zip(labels, disp, disp_std)):
            if sum(disp[i:])+sum(disp_std[i:]) == 0:
              break
            print(f'{label} = {disp_item:.5f} ± {disp_std_item:.5f} fs^{i+1}')
            last_item = disp_item+disp_std_item
        return disp, disp_std
    return wrapping
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it returns the same as before (at least for me).